# using gtktextbuffer and Pango

Tags: gtk, pango

I have some text in GtkTextBuffer with certain attribute properties like bold, italic.

I want to extract those text having those properties using Pango.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem possible at the moment. There is a [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=59390) and the issue is still open.